# How to understand this C macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am not able to understand this code

```
#define sqt(x) x*x
int main(){
print("%d",sqt(3+1));
}
```

Manually I am getting the output of 10. But when write the code and compile it I am getting the answer as 7. Please explain this.

Comment: How did you get 10?

Comment: 7 is the correct answer. If the want the answer to be 16, add some parentheses. I have no idea how to get to 10.

Comment: @kingW3 Maybe he meant `0x10`? :)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Or maybe he thinks it will expand to `3*3+1` for some reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember, since you're using a macro, `3 + 1` is not evaluated before `sqt` is called. `x` becomes `3 + 1` (not `4`), then order of operation causes an unexpected answer to be produced since addition happens after multiplication.

Or in other words:

```
sqt(3 + 1)
```

expands to:

```
3 + 1 * 3 + 1
```

Then, when you evaluate this like you would any other equation:

```
3 + 1 * 3 + 1 // Multiplication happens first
= 3 + 3 + 1
= 7
```

This is a good example of why you shouldn't use macros unless they're strictly necessary, or you've made proper care to ensure that things like order of operation mistakes don't happen. As @Barmar points out this particular case can be remedied by having the macro expand to include explicit parenthesis:

```
#define sqt(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Which would cause the evaluation to differ and give a proper answer:

```
(3 + 1) * (3 + 1)
4 * 4
16
```

Comment: You should show how to fix the macro so it works as intended.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should write your macros carefully.

Comment: @Barmar. Sadly, this macro will never result in 10 :)

Comment: Macros like this are perfectly fine, and there's no reason at all not to use them--as long as you include the parentheses.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The only reason to use macros like this is because you're using a 30-year-old compiler that doesn't optimize tiny functions by expanding them inline.

Comment: @Barmar Honestly, I know macros conceptually very well because of my familiarity with Clojure, but don't know C++ well enough to answer that. You could force order of operation by explicitly adding parenethsis in the macro definition, if that's the fix you're referring to. I suspect though that unless the call overhead really is a concern, a macro shouldn't be used here in the first place.

Comment: Exaclty. `#define sqt(x) (x*x)`

Comment: And while they're not really necessary, they're not uncommon, but neither are mistakes like this.

Comment: @Barmar Umm, no. Try again. Not nearly enough parentheses.

Comment: @user3386109 You got me. Macros like this really are a PITA.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, which I why I agree with  @ Carcigenicate's original advice to avoid macros. And agree with you that it's better to let the compiler inline tiny functions.